# Probability of poker cards using combinations, its a poker question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games, poker

Choose two cards from a regular 52 card deck, what is the probability of getting atleast one face card from the two card hand drawn? (Without replacement) What is the probability that the first card from the two cards you get is a facecard?  (fACE CARDS ARE K,Q AND J).

Part 2 What is the probability of getting atleast one face card in your hand of 2 choosen from 52.

Comment: so far for calculations if did 52C2 to figure out how many ways to choose 2 cards from a 52 deck, i have established there are 12 face cards. From the two cards i pick, i am not sure how to calculate that my first card will be a face and the second will not be face. Order matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: how many face-cards are there in a deck?

HINT2: what is the probability of not drawing any face card for the two cards in you hand?
*The first card has probability $\frac {40}{52}$ of not being a face card, the second one $\frac{39}{51}$. The probability of at least one face card is $1-\frac{40}{52}\frac{39}{51}$. (Why?)*
There are $52$ cards in the deck, with $40$ non face cards. The probability of drawing a non face card is thus $\frac {40}{52}$. now, there are $39$ non-face cards left, out of $51$, so the probability of another non-face card is $\frac{39}{51}$. The probability of two non-face cards is: $\frac{40}{52}\frac{39}{52}$. Now, drawing no face cards is the opposite of at least one face cards, so we get $1-\frac{40}{52}\frac{39}{51}$.

Does the  second card influence the probabilities for the first card?
*No, once the first card is drawn, you know (can calculate the probability) whether it is a face card or not. The second card isn't important anymore.*

Comment: there are 12 face cards in a deck.

Comment: 40/52 ? i am not sure

Comment: yes because for the question you only want the first card to be a facecard ....i might be wrong

Comment: Wow you totally right....i cant believe i didnt see this earlier...spent like 5 hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Can you help me with the part 2....for that part order doesnt matter

Comment: You can just draw only the first card from the deck and see whether or not it is a face card. The second card can't change what happened earlier, so the answer doesn't depend on that one.

Comment: ok so what i did to get part 2 of my question where the order of whether its in the first or second is

Comment: F1 = (52C2-40C2) then prob = F1/52C2

Comment: That looks fine to me and should give the same answer as my approach.

Comment: out of curisoity what is your approach because the way you do it seems much more understandable to me.

Comment: @Shawn edited my post

Comment: dont have enough rep to chat

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What is the chance of not drawing a face card in the first draw?  What is the probability of not drawing a face card in the second draw given that you did not draw a face card in the first draw? Call these $\lnot F_1$ and $\lnot F_2$, respectively.  What does $1-(\lnot F_1)(\lnot F_2)$ represent?